# Valid Set builder notations for simple set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, notation, quantifiers

So I have a simple set:

$\{ 1, 10, 100 \}$

I'm pretty sure one other way way I could represent it is:

$\{ 10^{m} : m \in \{0, 1, 2\} \}$

But I have a couple of other ideas for how to represent it. I just want to know if these other ways are possible or if any of these representations don't make sense. Here they are:

$\{ 10^{m} : \forall m \in \{0, 1, 2\} \}$

$\{ 10^{m} : \exists m \in \{0, 1, 2\} \}$

$\{ n : n = 10^{m} \text{ for some } m \text{ in } \{0, 1, 2\} \}$

If some of these are representations are invalid, I would love to know why.

Comment: One thing to remember about set builder notation is that it is not a "formal" thing - it is used to communicate in natural language mathematics papers. So some of the usage quirks may have no formal justification, they are just related to the way that the notation is ordinarily used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third one is valid, but the first two are not.

Let's go back to the original $\{ 10^m \mid m \in \{ 0,1,2 \} \}$

This we can read as 'the set of numbers $10^m$ for any $m$ for which it is true that $m \in \{0,1,2 \}$

But try doing that for $\{ 10^m \mid \forall m \ m \in \{ 0,1,2 \} \}$ ... now you get something like 'th set of numbers $10^m$ for any $m$ for which it is true that for all $m$ it is teue that $m \in \{0,1,2 \}$ ... that makes no sense. Same for the one after. The problem is that you need a predicate about $m$ after the $|$ and you don't have that once you quantify $m$, for then $m$ is no longer a free variable.

But the last one works again, for $n = 10^m$ for some $m \in \{0,1,2 \}$ is a predicate about $n$, as desired.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how about these ones too, just so I can have clarification:
$\{n : n=10^{m} \exists m \in \{0, 1, 2\} \}$

and

$\{n : n=10^{m} \forall m \in \{0, 1, 2\} \}$

Comment: @alanxoc3 that first one is a little weird ... people will probably understand it ok as 'for some m ...' but if you really use a logical quantifier there, you need to put it *before* any use of the $m$ that s being quantified, so it should be $\{ n : \exists m \ in \{0,1,2 \} n= 10^m \}$ ... and then it is fine. The second one is definitely not right, since again the quantifier needs to be moved in front, and so you end up saying that $n$ has to equal $1$, $10$, *and* $100$ all at once ... which is impossible ... and so you end up with an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Bram28 has already touched upon the specifics of your question, but I would like to offer an alternative: $$\bigcup_{m=0}^2\bigl\{ 10^m\bigr\} = \bigl\{ 10^0 \bigr\} \cup \bigl\{ 10^1 \bigr\} \cup \bigl\{ 10^2 \bigr\}$$

This denotes that $m$ **must** take **all** three values, not that it has to be **one of** the three values. I personally like this much more.